# Почему размер Red zone для Linux равен 128 байт?

Tags: linux, x86-64

Чем обусловлен именно такой размер [красной зоны](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing))?

Что ограничивает увеличение её размера и наоборот, почему в Windows её нет или она гораздо меньше?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно что бы сохранить 16-ть 64-х битных регистров.